# Why aren't my iframes loading at the same time?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have a script that I use to help me with some repetitive work, I have included a dummy of that script where I'm having issues, I have basically 2 pages.

The "main" page

```
<html>
<header>
</header>
<body>
<form name="ach" method="POST">
Text : <br><br><textarea rows="15" cols="50" name="ips">
</textarea><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="go"> 
</form>
</html>

<?php

if(!empty($_POST['go']))
{
    $ip = explode(PHP_EOL,trim($_POST['ips']));

    echo("<br><br>");
    for($i=0;$i<count($ip);$i++)
    {
echo("<font id='fefer'>Status</font> :   <iframe src='testo.php?fafa=$ip[$i]' width=150 height=70 id='haha$i'></iframe> </iframe>");    
    }
    echo("<br><br>");
}
?>
</body>
```

as you can it's just a regular form with a textarea that retrieve the text and devides it into lines and call another script on an iframe to deal with it

the "testo.php" page

```
    <?php
    
    
    if(!empty($_GET['fafa']))
    {
    echo($_GET['fafa']);
 //do stuff with the data
    sleep(10);
    echo("hehe");
    }
    ?>
```

the script seems dumb but i have removed the stuff in the middle just to avoid any confusion and to keep it clean , anyway the issue i'm having is that , usually i inset 10 lines on the "main" page , meaning that i will have 10 iframes treating data when i press submit , the issue is that no matter what i do , it always get excecuted 6 by 6 , no matter how many lines i put in there

i have insered a 10 sec delay on the "testo" page to visuale that issue in the script , if i put 3 lines on main.php , the iframes are excecuted simultaniosly , because it's less than 6 , but if i put 10 lines , the first 6 iframes get excecuted and the next ones won't start until the first 6 are over , if i put 30 lines , the first 6 get excecuted , then the next 6 start when the first 6 are over , then the 3rd 6 iframes won't start until the 2nd 6 batch is over...

i hope this makes sense , i included the script to test it out and get a better visual representation of my issue

anyhow , my question is , how can i "force" my script to excecute all the iframes at once , i tried purchasing a bigger vps but that haven't change anything , it doesn't matter if it slows down the site since this isn't being made for the general public

cheers

Answer (score 0):

As best I understand it, each iFrame makes a separate request to the server. Chrome has a limit of [6 connections to a single server](https://blog.bluetriangle.com/blocking-web-performance-villain#:%7E:text=Chrome%20has%20a%20limit%20of,host%20at%20the%20same%20time.&text=While%20Chrome%20can%20only%20handle,can%20handle%20up%20to%2017.) at a time. You might get a better solution if you asked how to accomplish your goal, rather than how to handle a symptom. I'm surprised you need more than 10 iFrames, for instance.

Comment: My goal is to connect to 10 different servers via SSH (at minimum) , i accomplished that with phpseclib , and bash a shell script that takes 3 minutes to finish.

the first issue is that if the ssh connection is closed , the shell script stops working (i tried looking for a way to keep it working even if the connection is closed but i couldn't)

so running a loop won't work for me since it will take forever , if i run it the way i have it in the script above i manage to connect to 6 servers and do the work for less than 4 minutes ... but anything above that takes forever